# Maven parent pom - module names in camel case?

Tags: maven, syntax, maven-3

Can module names in a maven aggregator (multi-module) project be in camel case?

Comment: you should handle artifactId's and groupId like package names in Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think module names follow the same conventions as artifactId.

> artifactId is the name of the jar without version. If you created it, then you can choose whatever name you want with lowercase letters and no strange symbols. If it's a third party jar, you have to take the name of the jar as it's distributed.
> eg. maven, commons-math

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

> The value of `<module>` is the relative path from the com.mycompany.app:my-app:1 to com.mycompany.app:my-module:1's POM (by practice, we use the module's artifactId as the module directory's name).

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#the-solution-2

Comment: If you can find the specific doc reference and change "I think" to "I know" in your answer, then I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: There reason I wrote “I think” is because I can’t find it. It is a folder name and I would try to keep it equal to the artifactId to avoid confusion. Especially because I often work on windows where case sensitivity and file systems don’t agree with each other. I fear this is a personal preference, not a rule.

Comment: Found a reference in the documentation. Added it to my answer. Doesn’t look like a hard rule, but rather a common practice.